# Bootstrap annoying float

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<body>
        <div class="wrap-site">
         <!--Header-->
            <header>
                <div class="inner">
                    <a id="logo" href="/levgronare" title="City Gross startsida">
                        <img id="big" src="images/citygross_logo_2013.png" alt="City Gross - Där maten gör skillnad">
                        <img id="small" src="images/cg_smalllogo.png" alt="City Gross - Där maten gör skillnad">
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://www.citygross.se/" class="back-button-link">Till citygross.se »</a>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="container"> 
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                        <img src="images/Landmann_Taurus.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Rök- och grilltunna</h2>
                        <p> Landmann Taurus smoker kan användas som en vanlig grill för direkt och indirekt grillning, men man kan även tillämpa äkta barbeque tack vare sidobehållaren på grillen.Det gör att temperaturen inne i den stora behållaren blir låg. Skorstenen skapar ett luftdrag som för rök och värme igenom den stora behållaren. Grillyta 66x36cm. Strl. 140x120x53 cm. Ord. pris 2299:-/st. <span class="price">SPARA 300:-</span> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Dorado.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Grillvagn</h2>
                        <p> Landmann Dorado, Strl. 134x114x63 cm, grillyta: 57x42 cm. Dorado kolgrill är en funktionsrik grill med många smarta funktioner. Man kan enkelt höja och sänka glödbädden med en vev och styr därmed enkelt värmen.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Klotgrill.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Klotgrill</h2>
                        <p> Landmann 47 cm. Klotgrill med emaljerat lock och grillskål. Grillgaller med en grillyta på Ø44 cm. Kolavskiljare för indirekt grillning. Askhylla undertill som lätt kan tas loss och tömmas.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Klotgrill.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Klotgrill</h2>
                        <p> Landmann 47 cm. Klotgrill med emaljerat lock och grillskål. Grillgaller med en grillyta på Ø44 cm. Kolavskiljare för indirekt grillning. Askhylla undertill som lätt kan tas loss och tömmas.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

My row wraps all the columns, is this the way to go?

What my issue is, is that the 3rd entry does not get aligned correctly. The 4th does, but 3rd just leaves white space and jumps down under the row its supposed to be in.

What am I doing wrong? http://gyazo.com/05f1b0719ac28ba3ac12f8352bbf1f43

Comment: try to post all your code / a demo to help you better

Comment: Should be container -> row -> col-xx-x

Comment: That is probably because, if I am not mistaken there are only 12 total grid values.  By doing col-sm-6 you are getting half of the row.  Try col-sm-4 (12/3 = 4)

Answer (score 1):

Your `col-sm-` should be in `row`.

You should use like this :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to jobworxx</title>
    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/media.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,400italic,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <body>
        <div class="wrap-site">
         <!--Header-->
            <header>
                <div class="inner">
                    <a id="logo" href="/levgronare" title="City Gross startsida">
                        <img id="big" src="images/citygross_logo_2013.png" alt="City Gross - Där maten gör skillnad">
                        <img id="small" src="images/cg_smalllogo.png" alt="City Gross - Där maten gör skillnad">
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://www.citygross.se/" class="back-button-link">Till citygross.se »</a>
                </div>
            </header>

            <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                        <img src="images/Landmann_Taurus.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Rök- och grilltunna</h2>
                        <p> Landmann Taurus smoker kan användas som en vanlig grill för direkt och indirekt grillning, men man kan även tillämpa äkta barbeque tack vare sidobehållaren på grillen.Det gör att temperaturen inne i den stora behållaren blir låg. Skorstenen skapar ett luftdrag som för rök och värme igenom den stora behållaren. Grillyta 66x36cm. Strl. 140x120x53 cm. Ord. pris 2299:-/st. <span class="price">SPARA 300:-</span> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Dorado.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Grillvagn</h2>
                        <p> Landmann Dorado, Strl. 134x114x63 cm, grillyta: 57x42 cm. Dorado kolgrill är en funktionsrik grill med många smarta funktioner. Man kan enkelt höja och sänka glödbädden med en vev och styr därmed enkelt värmen.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Klotgrill.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Klotgrill</h2>
                        <p> Landmann 47 cm. Klotgrill med emaljerat lock och grillskål. Grillgaller med en grillyta på Ø44 cm. Kolavskiljare för indirekt grillning. Askhylla undertill som lätt kan tas loss och tömmas.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Klotgrill.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Klotgrill</h2>
                        <p> Landmann 47 cm. Klotgrill med emaljerat lock och grillskål. Grillgaller med en grillyta på Ø44 cm. Kolavskiljare för indirekt grillning. Askhylla undertill som lätt kan tas loss och tömmas.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements often don't get their height calculated properly.
You can do the following:

- After every 6 cols you put a  which clears the float and recalculates the height of the parent div.
- Start a new row for every 6 cols because row has a clear float on the :after anyway.

Also i'd put the row inside a container, not the other way around so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
        <div class="wrap-site">
         <!--Header-->
            <header>
                <div class="inner">
                    <a id="logo" href="/levgronare" title="City Gross startsida">
                        <img id="big" src="images/citygross_logo_2013.png" alt="City Gross - Där maten gör skillnad">
                        <img id="small" src="images/cg_smalllogo.png" alt="City Gross - Där maten gör skillnad">
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://www.citygross.se/" class="back-button-link">Till citygross.se »</a>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                        <img src="images/Landmann_Taurus.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Rök- och grilltunna</h2>
                        <p> Landmann Taurus smoker kan användas som en vanlig grill för direkt och indirekt grillning, men man kan även tillämpa äkta barbeque tack vare sidobehållaren på grillen.Det gör att temperaturen inne i den stora behållaren blir låg. Skorstenen skapar ett luftdrag som för rök och värme igenom den stora behållaren. Grillyta 66x36cm. Strl. 140x120x53 cm. Ord. pris 2299:-/st. <span class="price">SPARA 300:-</span> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Dorado.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Grillvagn</h2>
                        <p> Landmann Dorado, Strl. 134x114x63 cm, grillyta: 57x42 cm. Dorado kolgrill är en funktionsrik grill med många smarta funktioner. Man kan enkelt höja och sänka glödbädden med en vev och styr därmed enkelt värmen.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Klotgrill.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Klotgrill</h2>
                        <p> Landmann 47 cm. Klotgrill med emaljerat lock och grillskål. Grillgaller med en grillyta på Ø44 cm. Kolavskiljare för indirekt grillning. Askhylla undertill som lätt kan tas loss och tömmas.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Klotgrill.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Klotgrill</h2>
                        <p> Landmann 47 cm. Klotgrill med emaljerat lock och grillskål. Grillgaller med en grillyta på Ø44 cm. Kolavskiljare för indirekt grillning. Askhylla undertill som lätt kan tas loss och tömmas.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Grid System : [click here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)
I thinks you got Answer.

- Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
  .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
- Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

i.e

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">...</div>
</div>
```

i.e. for row structure

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the pattern should be `container`, `row`, finally with `col-xx-x`.
Then, you may imagine that `row` is something like `table tr`.
You may do with this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">1</div>
     <div class="col-md-6">2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">3</div>
     <div class="col-md-6">4</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
        <div class="wrap-site">
         <!--Header-->
            <header>
                <div class="inner">
                    <a id="logo" href="/levgronare" title="City Gross startsida">
                        <img id="big" src="images/citygross_logo_2013.png" alt="City Gross - Där maten gör skillnad">
                        <img id="small" src="images/cg_smalllogo.png" alt="City Gross - Där maten gör skillnad">
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://www.citygross.se/" class="back-button-link">Till citygross.se »</a>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="container"> 
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                        <img src="images/Landmann_Taurus.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Rök- och grilltunna</h2>
                        <p> Landmann Taurus smoker kan användas som en vanlig grill för direkt och indirekt grillning, men man kan även tillämpa äkta barbeque tack vare sidobehållaren på grillen.Det gör att temperaturen inne i den stora behållaren blir låg. Skorstenen skapar ett luftdrag som för rök och värme igenom den stora behållaren. Grillyta 66x36cm. Strl. 140x120x53 cm. Ord. pris 2299:-/st. <span class="price">SPARA 300:-</span> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Dorado.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Grillvagn</h2>
                        <p> Landmann Dorado, Strl. 134x114x63 cm, grillyta: 57x42 cm. Dorado kolgrill är en funktionsrik grill med många smarta funktioner. Man kan enkelt höja och sänka glödbädden med en vev och styr därmed enkelt värmen.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Klotgrill.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Klotgrill</h2>
                        <p> Landmann 47 cm. Klotgrill med emaljerat lock och grillskål. Grillgaller med en grillyta på Ø44 cm. Kolavskiljare för indirekt grillning. Askhylla undertill som lätt kan tas loss och tömmas.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entry-image">
                            <img src="images/Landmann_Klotgrill.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Klotgrill</h2>
                        <p> Landmann 47 cm. Klotgrill med emaljerat lock och grillskål. Grillgaller med en grillyta på Ø44 cm. Kolavskiljare för indirekt grillning. Askhylla undertill som lätt kan tas loss och tömmas.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```